# ADC code won't work as intended

Tags: avr, adc

Ive been able to come up with the code below, trying to measure the voltages from three channels using the interrupt method. while the code runs without aby errors, im still unable to display anything on the lcd after having measured. 
im no pro in avr stuff, just started a few months back. 
any help is highly appreciated`

```
ISR(ADC_vect)                                   //selecting between multiple adc channels
{
    char buffer[10];
    uint8_t theLow = ADCL;
    uint16_t theTenBitResult = ADCH<<8 | theLow;

    switch(ADMUX)
    {
        case 0x20:
        //calculate temperature
        temperature = ((theTenBitResult) * 1024/5);
        _delay_ms(10);
        ADMUX = 0x21;
        break;

        case 0x21:
        //calculate and print voltage
        voltage  = ((theTenBitResult * 1024/5) * (1324675/324675));         //1M plus 300k voltage divider resistor values
        dtostrf(voltage, 5, 2, buffer);
        //sprintf(buffer, "%f", voltage);                           //as lcd library does not include int and float conversion to string is necessary
        lcd_gotoxy(11,0);
        lcd_puts(buffer);
        _delay_ms(10);
        ADMUX = 0x22;
        break;

        case 0x22:
        //calculate and print current
        current = ((theTenBitResult * 1024/5) * 1.5);                       //1.5 is the maximum current range expected
        lcd_gotoxy(11,1);
        sprintf(buffer, "%f", current);
        lcd_puts(buffer);
        _delay_ms(10);
        ADMUX = 0x20;
        break;

        default:
        //don,t expect any value here
        break;
    } ;
        ADCSRA |= 1<<ADSC;
}`
```

Comment: LCD operations and delays in particular are a very, very bad idea inside an interrupt handler.

Comment: Interrupts should be kept as short as possible. I think it's a pretty bad idea to put 10ms delay here.

Comment: Another small bit of advice, since I don't see where ADMUX is being initialized, is set ADMUX to some valid value in the default branch of the switch statement

Comment: Can we assume that you've tried displaying "Hello World" on the LCD using this exact code with just the ADC parts commented out?

Comment: I would probably use a global for the ADC result (you may have to declare it volatile), grab the result, set some flag and get out of the handler (as already noted, it should be as short as possible).

Comment: What value do you initialize `ADMUX` to? Can you show us the code that sets up and starts the ADC?

Answer (score 1):

1. it is not a good practice to put so much into an isr.
2. it is not a good practice to put the same routines in the isr as well as outside of the isr.
3. restart the adc at the beginning of the isr to save some time.